# Can I edit a GitHub repo without the permission of the owner?

Tags: github

I want to keep working on [this repo](https://github.com/mdn522/expertoptionapi). How can I keep working on it?

I mean can I update it in my own repo? Will this make any legal problems?

I want to add the possibility to buy and sell, and more things to this API.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not keep working on a repo without the required permissions.

You can fork a repo, and continue working on it on your own that way.

[More info on forking a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)